# Impact of rain fade on 60 GHz radio links

Tags: rf, propagation, humidity, wavelength

I'm a junior network admin at an ISP and need your help regarding point-to-point links with devices using the 60 GHz band.

**PROBLEM**

Most of them, except the ones that are at very close proximity (e.g., 300 m), go down during bad weather; longer links (e.g., 6 km) go down even when there is fog while shorter ones (1.2 km) require heavy rainfall to exhibit that behavior.

**DEVICE SPECIFICATIONS**

We have used devices from multiple vendors and installed them according to the manufacturer's instructions. In most cases, for example, we are well within the possible maximum range suggested by the manufacturer (also, RSSI is perfect in good weather) so it's not that we're using them in ways not intended by the manufacturer.

**WHAT I'M ASKING**

I would like you to help me understand the physics behind rain fade and suggest practical solutions to the problem. Would going for more expensive equipment (advertised as having longer reach) help at all, or is the problem solely related to the interaction between 60 GHz frequencies and humidity and thus insurmountable? Can we do anything else? For instance, I have seen radio covers being sold to protect against ice build-up on the radio.

We don't want to move away from 60 GHz links because of their low latencies and high throughput, unless, of course, there is no way to overcome the rain fade issue.

Comment: Please provide a link to the equipment and draw a schematic showing how you used it.

Comment: https://www.fcc.gov/file/14379/download

Comment: @Andyaka Excellent explanation in that document.

Comment: Giorgos, I don't know how definitive @Andyaka 's doc. But Figure 3 would appear to me to strongly suggest problems at 6 km, regardless. The band is literally designed to target O2 resonance. And since the atmosphere is 20% O2, distance isn't its forte. Bad weather would almost certainly cause additional problems. You could ask the suppliers to perform a root-cause evaluation of your situation (they may want money) or ask them what kind of equipment and measurements to take, if you want to DIY that root-cause evaluation. Maybe they may be over-selling it. You may need to prove that, though.

Comment: Hey thank you all for chipping in. Well, product specifications say that the device is meant to support 12+ km (ubiquiti airfiber 60 lr) so 6 should not have been an issue or at least the link should not be going down in light rain or fog. Boss at work said we could try getting a device that supports 15km but I don't think that will work either. And, if I understand Andy's document correctly, we will definitely notice no improvement. Thing is I'm only just getting into wireless communications (no background in physics either) by necessity so I'm sorry if what I'm asking should be a no-brainer.

Comment: @GiorgosA I think your question was well-framed. Until I skimmed through Andy's doc, I had no knowledge of this band. (I'm ignorant that way.) So I learned some things, too. And I think this is more likely an issue regarding marketing statements vs reality. I'm sure that the simple chart (Figure 3) doesn't capture all of the relevant knowledge. It's just a simple chart, after all, and can only provide a general perspective. But it is pretty disheartening to see, too, for longer distances and it would make me want to ask some very pointed questions of the product manufacturer and supplier.

Comment: Marketing for radio gear that suggests maximum range is basically always 'wildly optimistic', only question is by how much. My usual rule of thumb if I cannot get the numbers to calculate a proper link budget is to take the marketing number and divide by 5 or so to get something that might work well enough to be useful as opposed to sort of working, some of the time, I figure two or three km in free space for that kit if I wanted reliability, especially in weather.

Comment: Can you update your question with details of the actual "60 GHz" frequencies being used on your links, and whether things improve if you push the frequencies up to the top of the range?

Comment: What country are you in? That would have an impact on regulations and thus on frequencies, max power, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a good summary of rain fade at 60 GHz here ["Is There Rain Fade on 60 GHz Wireless Signals?"](https://blog.linitx.com/rain-fade-60ghz)

This includes estimates of attenuation for various levels of rain:

- Drizzle     (.25 mm/h) 0.2 dB/km
- Light Rain  (2.5 mm/h) 1.8 dB/km
- Medium Rain (12. 5mm/h) 5.6 dB/km
- Heavy Rain  (25 mm/h) 9.5 dB/km
- Downpour    (50 mm/h) 17 dB/km
- Tropical    (100 mm/h) 28 dB/km
- Monsoon     (200 mm/h) 38 dB/km

However, as noted in both the above article and this [60 GHz background doc](https://www.fcc.gov/file/14379/download) (link provided by "Andy aka" in the comments to your question), the O2 resonance means there is an attenuation of 15+ dB per km (over and above any Free Space Path Loss) at the band center frequency.

This may seem to make 60 GHz a poor choice for comms links, but is actually why the 60 GHz band was approved for unlicensed use, as the high distance related losses mean many links can be used in relatively close proximity, without needing coordination to avoid interference.  As a result, except in really heavy rainfall, the O2 loss term is normally the dominant factor on overall link loss budget.

At heart this is therefore a question about RF link design.

Your weather SNR (signal to noise) margin, is what you've got left once you have accounted for:

- Transmit power
- Receiver sensitivity
- Free Space Path Loss (FSPL) determined by the transmit and receive antennas, and the accuracy of their alignment
- Any objects in the effective beam path, which widens significantly in the middle of the beam relative to the antenna sizes
- the base O2 absorption loss
- coding/modulation effects.

This can all be calculated by hand (as I've done many times in the past), but manufacturers often now provide very usable online tools for designing and evaluating networks of links using their own equipment.

For instance this [tool](https://ispdesign.ui.com/) from Ubiquity vastly simplifies the process using their 60 GHz gear, and would definitely be the one to use if you are using their kit, not least as it gives a basis for getting support if the don't deliver in reality.

However, it is really important to look at all the options provided in these tools...

If you use the Ubiquity tools at "60 GHz", and you leave "Frequency" set at the default "Wave AI", they claim very long link lengths (10Km+) are stable.  But if you set a specific frequency of 60.48 GHz (the middle of the 60 GHz band), suddenly any link above about 2km is marginal in the dry, and fails in the wet.

What's going on?

Well, digging further, it looks like the "Wave AI" option on the airFibre 60 XR bridges "works" by shifting the operating frequency up as high as 69120 MHz.

This graph from the FCC doc referenced earlier, shows why moving to higher frequencies (some outside the commonly approved band) makes such a difference, as the impact of the O2 resonance is vastly reduced.
[image]

This appears to be a common issue with 60GHz equipment providers, with their maximum claimed ranges often only achievable when using frequencies almost at 70 GHz, but in many countries (including the US) this is **not** compatible with the unlicensed 60 GHz band.

In the case of Ubiquiti datasheets, this is all covered by a "* Depends on regulatory region."...

I would therefore strongly suggest you start by checking link performance in the manufacturer's tools **at you actual operating frequency**.  This analysis can then be checked out relative to the actual link margin (which you should be able to observe via the Tx/Rx management interfaces)*

**In terms of solving your problem,** the above diagram shows that you should push the frequencies you are using on your links as high as possible.  And if there are interference issues, use the highest frequencies on your longest links.  This will minimize the impact of the O2 resonance, and could make a massive difference to the margin for weather conditions.

(Also worth noting that at 60 GHz, antenna alignment is much more critical than with say a 2.4 GHz link. For a 12" dish, the beam width is ~4 deg, so precise and stable alignment is critical. Failure to do this will have a massive impact on link stability, but this should be visible on the setup tools as a gap between the predicted and actual link margins.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I've learned still more about how to think about this topic and I am in your debt for it. +1

Comment: I've just added clearer guidance on using the highest frequency you can on the longer links to maximize SNR margin.  Would love to know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my question. So I can't accept it. ;)

Comment: @periblepsis One day I will learn to both read, and actually process what I'm reading ;-)

Comment: @periblepsis Just reworked the answer to hopefully make it more coherent, rather than reflecting the piece-wise investigation of the Ubiquity tools and docs.

Comment: @colintd Your answer has been most helpful! So we should notice better performance on the higher end of the band because of moving away from the oxygen absorption frequency. Well I'm not sure which exact frequencies we are using as another guy is setting them up so I have to check with him. Just need to clarify something: with the higher frequencies we only avoid oxygen absorption not the attenuation resulting from wet weather, right? If that is the case, I'm afraid that will not work either because our problem is exclusively rain-bound. But it couldn't hurt to try :) Thanks all!

Comment: If you reduce the O2 losses, then the SNR margin on the link will increase.  This will then make the link more tolerant of rain losses.  You can see this on the ubiquity modelling tool, which allows you to simulate various rain losses.  If you increase the frequency, link margin improves, and the level at which rain causes link degradation increases very significantly.  2km at 60 GHz is marginal in the dry.  By the time you are at 68 GHz, 10Km in medium rain doesn't even slow.

Comment: You're the man! We'll check it out. Really appreciate it that you took the time to write such a clearly formulated answer :)

Comment: Happy to help, but do let us know whether this solves/improves your situation.  Old and new frequencies and SNR margins would be great to know, along with place in the world (to understand regulatory regime).

Comment: Did this work for you? Others might find the answer really useful.